Ensure macOS mail application is downloading and keeping locally all messages with IMAP
I have an IMAP email account.
I am reading my e-mails with macOS Mail application.
Emails are kept on server.
It seems they are also kept locally but I am not sure if it is a temporary cache.
Is there a way to be sure ALL emails (and attachment) will be kept on my local computer ?
Thanks

The way IMAP works is that the copies of the mail on your machine are in sync with those on the server. If you delete a mail on either it will be deleted on the other. Is this what you're after?

If you are looking for a way to incrementally back up your e-mail accounts,  Backup and restore IMAP mail account with (open source) Linux tools should help.

You could ask if your provider has POP3 access. POP doesn't synchronise mail, it merely downloads it to any client that doesn't yet have a copy. After some period configurable at the client, old emails are deleted from the server; the client copy remains with no further action required. I do this myself because I want all mail archived on my Mac, without having to keep any on my phone, once dealt with.

You can create in your mail.app a "local folder" (on my Mac) and copy all emails there, so if you delete mail from IMAP server you'll always have a local copy.
All files resident locally on your Mac, can be backed up with Time Machine.


Emails are kept on server.

This is correct.  Whether you are using a webmail client (think GMail’s web interface) or a local client like Apple Mail, these are just local clients that access the server.

It seems they are also kept locally but I am not sure if it is a temporary cache.

They are cached locally. This enables offline viewing of your mail; not offline storage. Remember, the server is considered the master here.  Should the account be locked or terminated or instructed that a message is no longer accessible, that local cache won’t be of any use.

Is there a way to be sure ALL emails (and attachment) will be kept on my local computer ?

Create a local folder (off of the server) to which you want to ensure is archived permanently. Some mail clients (I use Outlook) has locally stored rules in which you could have every incoming and outgoing message copied to that archival folder.

How do you create this folder ? Are you talking about a folder on the filesystem or a folder in mail application ? Thanks

You can create a folder within the mail app itself

It will create a folder on the server too ?

You can create folders on and off the server. Have you tried?

@Allan If you create the folder in the "On My Mac" container, it only exists on your computer, not the server.
